# C# object from settings

Tags: c#, xml, settings, config, code-injection

What's the appropriate way to design the following application:

I have some `IAlgorithm` objects, each of them has it's own settings. Obviously, I would like to store the settings in some settings file and easiest way to do it would be to utilize `app.config`.

*Now, I have an injection scheme, where objects using algorithms are set up the following way:*

```
Bind<IAlgorithm>.To(new SimpleAlgoritm(simpleAlgorithmSettings));
Bind<IAlgorithm>.To(new ComplicatedAlgoritm(complicatedAlgorithmSettings));
```

The first way that comes in mind would be to make something like:

```
var simpleAlgorithmSettings = DeserializeSimpleAlgorithmSettingsFromConfigFile();
```

and then pass them into the object bindings.

---

- **Still, I assume something better can be done here, but I can't come up
  with a really nice idea, so any help
  would be appreciated.**
- Also, what are the alternatives for
  the `app.config` usage for such
  cases?

Comment: Why not just serialize those settings to XML file? Have set of such XML's attached to your project or embedded as resources, and then use standard XML deserialization mechanism?

Comment: @Bashir Yep, this is what I claim as the obvious solution (app.config is also an `xml` file), however my mind keeps telling me this isn't the best approach for this case *(I guess something better could be done in terms of the injection-deserialization scheme).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use app.config, but let the single alorithm type to pick for his settings. From the algorithm code, even if it is declared in another dll, you always have the ConfigurationManager pointing to the current *application* config file.

Comment: And what would be the best way to implement this settings `picking` with respect to the used injection scheme?

Comment: I don't understand how this can make the difference for the IoC, just read the setting with ConfigurationManager.AppSettings from inside the algo implementation